# google map not working TRIED MANY TUTORIALS

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

i am tired working on google map,but could't find the bug,
 The error here is ""unfortunately bhk has stopped working""
I am posting my code here 
plz help me put
**THIS IS MY MANIFEST FILE**

*

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.example.bhk"
 android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">

  <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="12"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />


<permission android:name="com.example.bhk.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
     android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCAT"/>


<uses-feature
android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
android:required="true"/>

<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="AIzaSyAVqGlNT-a7_8IpOHFfE5GlBzL9pfmHCHM" />
   <meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:allowBackup="true">

<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name">
<intent-filter>
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
 </intent-filter>
 </activity>
 <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
</application>
</manifest>*
```

**THIS IS MY MAINACTIVITY FILE**

*

```
package com.example.bhk;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

*

**THIS IS MY ACTIVITYMAIN FILE**

*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

*

Sir the erroe in CONSOLE IS

[2014-03-05 03:16:54 - Android SDK] Warning when loading the SDK:

```
Warning: Missing file 'C:\Users\hp\.android\avd\bkj.avd\config.ini'.
[2014-03-05 03:20:31 - bhk] Dx 
trouble writing output: already prepared
[2014-03-05 03:20:35 - bhk] ------------------------------
[2014-03-05 03:20:35 - bhk] Android Launch!
[2014-03-05 03:20:35 - bhk] adb is running normally.
[2014-03-05 03:20:35 - bhk] Performing com.example.bhk.MainActivity activity launch
[2014-03-05 03:20:36 - bhk] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'google-API'
[2014-03-05 03:20:36 - bhk] Uploading bhk.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-03-05 03:20:41 - bhk] Failed to install bhk.apk on device 'emulator-5554': timeout
[2014-03-05 03:20:41 - bhk] Launch canceled!
```

WHILE LOGCAT SHOWS

```
03-04 16:57:28.424: E/NetdConnector(383): NDC Command {81 bandwidth gettetherstats} took too long (786ms)
```

BUT Running the apk on android device shows the error
Unfortunately abhk.apk has stopped

logcat after updating MANIFEST FILE.  @Emil

03-06 14:08:37.657: E/AndroidRuntime(1152): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-06 14:08:37.657: E/AndroidRuntime(1152): Process: com.example.bhk, PID: 1152
03-06 14:08:37.657: E/AndroidRuntime(1152): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity

found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=market://details?

id=com.google.android.gms flg=0x80000 pkg=com.android.vending }

03-06 14:08:37.657: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at

android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1632)

03-06 14:08:37.657: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at

android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)

03-06 14:08:37.657: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at

android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3424)
03-06 14:08:37.657: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at

android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3385)

03-06 14:08:37.657: E/AndroidRuntime(1152):     at 
android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:839)

Comment: Welcome to SO! What's not working exactly! Please tell us details!

Comment: ok. while running the apk file on emulator the error comes ,and app stops.

Comment: Please show us the error message!

Comment: and the logcat stack trace

Comment: your app isn't even running - it never loads into the emulator.

Comment: yes @martin ,thats why i tried it in android device,but there also error is coming.what to do next?

Answer (score 0):

You have some problems in the manifest file:

those parts:

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="AIzaSyAVqGlNT-a7_8IpOHFfE5GlBzL9pfmHCHM" />
   <meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```

should be under the `application` hive, and this part should be removed:

```
  <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

as it's part of the `Google Maps API V1`, like so:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name">
<intent-filter>
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
 </intent-filter>
 </activity>

 <meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="AIzaSyAVqGlNT-a7_8IpOHFfE5GlBzL9pfmHCHM" />
   <meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
</application>
```

another thing is that you are missing this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.bhk.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
```

In addition I suggest you yo go over this guide I wrote on this topic:

[Google Maps API V2 Guide](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)

Comment: @user3304690, if you have followed all the steps in the guide I posted here, then no error should be occurring. What do you see in the logcat?

Comment: sir,plz check latest edit for logcat ,but the emulator says to upgrade GOOGLE PLAY SERVICES, with an UPDATE button, which on clicking  crashes the application.

Comment: Of course it does, you can't check a google maps application on the emulator... you have to test it on a real device.

Comment: yes sir,after testing on my adroid phone ,the application crashes..tried it many times,